# What information is required to ReviseItem on a variation? ebay sdk api

Tags: c#, ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-net-sdk

**[EDIT] Instead of using ReviseItem I switched to ReviseInventoryStatus which is the correct method. Not sure why I have been using ReviseItem calls for the last few years. I am either dumb or some part of the api or docs changed and I never caught on. https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1641 [/EDIT]**

I need to update the stock count on variation listings and I am not 100% clear what is required. I am using the C# .Net ebay sdk. I am able to ReviseItem for single items just fine.

```
ItemType item = new ItemType();
item.ItemID = itemId;
item.Quantity = qty;
StringCollection deletedFields = new StringCollection();
ReviseItemCall apicall = new ReviseItemCall(apiContext);
apicall.ReviseItem(item, deletedFields, false);
```

I provide the ebay item id and the new qty. Easy peasy. From what I understand from the developer docs the requirements for a variation listing ReviseItem is the ebay item id AND the SKU/Custom Label.

```
ItemType item = new ItemType();
item.ItemID = itemId;
item.Quantity = qty;
item.SKU = sku;
StringCollection deletedFields = new StringCollection();
ReviseItemCall apicall = new ReviseItemCall(apiContext);
apicall.ReviseItem(item, deletedFields, false);
```

However when I call this I get the following error.

> eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiException: 'Item level quantity will be ignored. The sum of the quantities for all the variations will be used for the listing quantity.
>   Duplicate custom variation label.'

The customer label is not duplicated on this variation listing or in the entire store itself (which doesn't matter as far as I can see). What am I missing here? What else is required? I am 100% sure I am passing the correct ebay item id and customer labels to the sdk for updating.

Comment: [See](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=2104) that, what error code are you getting back?